# Tensorflow add broadcasting

Tags: tensorflow

Can someone tell me what's going on here? I'm confused.

```
In [125]: a
Out[125]: <tf.Tensor 'MatMul_86739:0' shape=(100, 1) dtype=float32>

In [126]: embed
Out[126]: <tf.Tensor 'embedding_lookup_41205:0' shape=(100,) dtype=float32>


In [128]: a+embed
Out[128]: <tf.Tensor 'add_43373:0' shape=(100, 100) dtype=float32>
```

How can (100,1) + (100,) be (100,100)? and if so, WHY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules for TensorFlow's broadcasting operators are based on [NumPy's broadcasting rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

The basic algorithm for broadcasting works from right to left. Assume we are adding (or applying another binary broadcasting operator to) two tensors `x` and `y`, the following code computes the shape of the result:

```
result_shape = []

# Loop over the matching dimensions of x and y in reverse.
for x_dim, y_dim in zip(x.shape[::-1], y.shape[::-1]):
  if x.shape == y.shape:
    result_shape.insert(0, x.shape)
  elif x.shape == 1:
    result_shape.insert(0, y.shape)  # x will be broadcast along this dimension.
  elif y.shape == 1:
    result_shape.insert(0, x.shape)  # y will be broadcast along this dimension.
  else:
    raise ValueError("Shapes of x and y are incompatible.")

# If x and y have a different rank, the leading dimensions are inherited
# from the tensor with higher rank.
if len(x.shape) > len(y.shape):
  num_leading_dims = len(x.shape) - len(y.shape)
  result_shape = x.shape[0:num_leading_dims] + result_shape
elif len(y.shape) > len(x.shape):
  num_leading_dims = len(y.shape) - len(x.shape)
  result_shape = y.shape[0:num_leading_dims] + result_shape
```

Now in your example, you have `x.shape = (100,)` and `y.shape = (100, 1)`:

1. The first comparison is between `100` and `1`, and so `result_shape = [100]`.
2. `y.shape` is longer than `x.shape`, so we add the leading dimension to the result, giving `result_shape = [100, 100]`.

Comment: Thank you so much @mrry I respect you so much!!